# install4j Unix installer supported on AIX?

Tags: install4j

Will a Unix installer created with install4j work on AIX as well? Or is there a way/need to create installers for different flavors of Unix? I would have tried it on AIX but I don't have ready access at this moment.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried it on AIX, but I have successfully created unix installers that work just fine with Linux and Solaris. I'm guessing if you have a JRE, it will work.

Comment: Correct, if the Unix has a POSIX-compatible shell and a functioning JRE, the installer will work.